# Calculating the mode of the posterior distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, posterior

Need help .Which one is supposed to be the mode for posterior distribution based on the spreadsheet presented below? I cannot put forward an entire spreadsheet(as there are 100+ rows) so here is the picture of first few? Will it be the maximum value of posterior distribution or its corresponding theta?

[image: Figure]

Comment: What is a "theta"?

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying(it is my first post in here) , theta is the mean rate of arrival of vehicle in an intersection/hour from 30 to 70 with a step of 0.1

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?  Theta is a *mean,* not a mode.

Comment: oh thank you very much, silly me

Comment: I think you should look at the theta value which gives the biggest logpost value.